# Jquery display closest images

Tags: jquery, css

I have this div, inside the div I have a paragraph and inside the paragraph I have an image.

360 Sweaters

I am trying to display the closest image when I hover over my paragraph with this code:

```
$(function(){
                $('.entry-content p').hover(function(){
                    //alert('heeeeey');
                    $('.entry-content p').css('width', '100%');
                    $('.entry-content p').closest('img').css('display', 'block');
                });
            });
```

But when I goto hover over my paragraph, the image does not display. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: why don't you try `$('.entry-content p').closest('img').show()` instead?

Comment: I think you misunderstood "closest", "closest" will match ancestor nodes, use "find" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.cloest()` is to find the the first match ancestor in the dom tree. A `p` element won't have ancestor which is a image.

If the image is inside the `p` element, try `$('.entry-content p').find('img')`,

If the image is next to the `p` element, try `$('.entry-content p').next('img')`.

Comment: find() really did help, but I have other paragraphs and I only want to display the image for only 1 paragraph, thats why i thought cloest() would work